# Identify a movie about alien who doesn't like to eat meat

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I watched this movie when I was a kid. Now, I'd like to rewatch it again but have no idea what the title is. Here's what I remember:

- It's around 1990's - 2000's
- I remember this scene: the alien and a human hide in a bush, then the human eats a fried chicken and the alien says it's barbaric to eat animal meat.
- There's a scene of a burned school or church (not really sure).
- There's also a scene of a shootout using a laser gun (not really sure).
- The alien is furry and has bright colors (not really sure).

That's all I can remember.

Comment: Hi Vahn. Thank you for submitting your question. Too, for putting in as much detail as you could remember. To your note, this may be a tough one to identify as there is not much to go on.  Are there any other details you can help provide?  E.g. where did you watch it? In what language was it broadcast?  Was it animated or live-action?  Etc.  Anything else you can provide may help.

Comment: @beichst My question has been answered by FuzzyBoots. Thanks for your attention

Comment: Great to hear Vahn. Nice work FuzzyBoots1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it possible that you have mixed memories of *[Masters of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_of_the_Universe_(film))*? It was released in 1987, close to your timeframe. There is a scene where fried chicken is noted to be barbaric:

> **Teela**: I wonder why they put the food on these little white sticks?
> **Man-at-Arms**: Those are rib bones. 
> **Teela**: (stops chewing) You mean this used to be an animal...? 
> **Man-at-Arms**: Uh-huh. 
> **Teela**: Ugh! What a barbaric world...

### The chicken scene

They do use laser guns to fight and one of the characters, Gwildor, is a colorful furry alien:

[image: Gwildor]

Here is the trailer for the film in case that might seem familiar:

Comment: ^_^ Lucky Google search turned up the [Alien Lunch](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AlienLunch) trope mentioning it, and then the rest of it fell out of my memories.