# 80's or 90's sci fi movie title that has a mace?

Tags: story-identification

I have been trying to figure out what this movie is for over 20 years. All I remember is some barbarian type dude is looking for a mace ball or beeper type transmission device in some convinience store. I want to know the name so bad I literally just woke up from a dream where Chuck Norris told the movie is called "The Spike." It's not. It's not called "The Spike."

Comment: So was he looking for a mace or for a beeper? Or was it a beeper in the shape of a mace?

Comment: What else did Chuck say?

Comment: Man, I don't remember. I have asked people for years about this. Yea, I just had a dream so amazing I texted a friend in Scotland about it. Basically ended up on the junkyard set of Robo Cop...apparently all the 80's action heroes hang together as Norris showed up. He just said the movie was called the spike when I bizarrely asked action super star Chuck Norris, not for an autograph or why he did Walker Texas Ranger, but about an obscure sci fi movie no one has ever watched. We double high fived and I said "the memes are true, Chuck Norris is the greatest." Turns out Chuck was wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138750/identify-a-movie-about-alien-who-doesnt-like-to-eat-meat

Answer (score 12):

Is it possible that you're thinking of the 1987 *[Masters of the Universe](http://he-man.wikia.com/wiki/Masters_of_the_Universe_(film))* movie? The Cosmic Key, which indeed looks mace-like and emits beeping sounds, winds up at a music store.

[image: Cosmic Key in action] [image: Cosmic key held in hand]

Dolph Lundgren plays He-Man and he certainly fits the barbarian stereotype.

[image: He-Man]

### Trailer

Comment: This might be it. Memory is a fickle mistress.

Comment: The trailer is at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CF20B8p4F08. The full movie looks to have been posted as well...

Comment: From what I remember the barbarian was a villian. I did not even watch the entire movie, but have wanted to forever. I want to think the barbarian found a beeper type thing in some candy bar box and was saying "ball" as in a mace ball. I don't know. This will make me a crazy person.

Comment: The scene where He-Man shows up is at https://youtu.be/VVisd9ihWv0?t=55m55s FWIW.

Comment: I am almost certain this is not it, but it is similar. My memory could be entirely shot. I don't remember He-Man at all. There were some kids or teens involved which makes this movie an even more likely candidate. Was there ever another barbarian type dide looking for what He-Man was looking for? (The scene you sent is not working on youtube.) I will try to find it though.

Comment: There's a guy in black spikey armor and an eyepatch on the side of the bad guys who also shows up on the scene and swordfights He-Man. Blade seems to be his name.

Comment: This must be it but my memory is different. This was 25 years ago. I think I might be mixing up the appearances of Blade and Beast Man. I am not 100% sure. There was another movie I always wanted to know that had a scene where some dude is being whipped. I always thought it was Flash Gordon but now I know this is it. I must have seen bits and pieces of this movie and mixed in all up in my child brain. How does Chuck Norris not know his boy Dolphs movie? Thanks Fuzzy Boots!

Comment: :) If you think it is the right answer, can you click on the checkmark by the voting buttons? You can always change it if you change your mind.

Comment: Still not sure it is He-Man. Could be but I know this movie involved a ball of some sort. Apparently there are a good many sci fi movies that involve some type of magical sphere of some sort. I am still looking. This is now an obsession and I will never rest!